# Apache CXF Policy Exception Reference to policy X509 Authentication, Signature and Encryption could not be resolved

Tags: java, cxf, wss4j

Am trying to call third party web service using java apache CXF. I created the proxy using CXF apache plugin. The service is protected using X509 Authentication, Signature and Encryption.

When I call the service, am getting the  below exception.

```
Apache CXF Policy Exception Reference to policy  "X509 Authentication, Signature and Encryption" could not be resolved
```

This is what I tried sofar..

```
ServiceEnq service=new ServiceEnq(new
URL("https://.....Inquiry?wsdl"));

System.out.println("Line2 scuccess!");

InquiryPortType port=service.getInquiryPort();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);


org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();


HashMap<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION,
"UsernameToken Timestamp Signature Encryption");

outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "username1");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());

outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_USER, "public1");

outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_FILE, "publicProp.properties");


outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_USER, "pk"); 
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "pkProp.properties");
outProps.put("timeToLive", "30");

WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

HashMap<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Encryption Signature Timestamp");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.DEC_PROP_FILE, "publicProp.properties");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "pkProp.properties");

WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

ObjectFactory fact=new ObjectFactory();

InquiryRequest request=fact.createInquiryRequest();
MessageHeaderIn headerIn=fact.createMessageHeaderIn(); 


// removed input parameters
```

**// getting error in this line...**

> InquiryResponse2 res=      port.Inquiry(request);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manually created the XML `Document` and used `wss4j` to encrypt and sign XML document. Then uploaded the generated SOAP envelope to `HttpURLConnection` using POST method.

Here is the java code to sign and encryption. I have avoided other code as this is more tricky part..

> 

```
public void addSignature(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", SecurityConstants.JKSPassword);

        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file",
                SecurityConstants.ClientCert);

        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias",
                SecurityConstants.ClientKeyAliasName);
        Merlin keyMaterialCrypto = new Merlin(properties);

        WSSecSignature wssSign = new WSSecSignature();
        wssSign.setUserInfo(SecurityConstants.ClientKeyAliasName, SecurityConstants.JKSPassword);

        wssSign.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.X509_KEY_IDENTIFIER);

        wssSign.setUseSingleCertificate(false);

        org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();

        secHeader.setMustUnderstand(false);
        secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

        wssSign.build(doc, keyMaterialCrypto, secHeader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }

}

public void addEnccryption(Document doc) {
    StringWriter writer = null;
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", SecurityConstants.JKSPassword);
        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file",
                SecurityConstants.ServerCer);
        properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias",
                SecurityConstants.ServerAliasName);

        Merlin crypto = new Merlin(properties);

        WSSecEncrypt wsEncryption = new WSSecEncrypt();

        WSSConfig wssConfig = WSSConfig.getNewInstance();
        wsEncryption.setWsConfig(wssConfig);
        wsEncryption.setUserInfo(SecurityConstants.ServerAliasName);
        wsEncryption.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.X509_KEY_IDENTIFIER);
        wsEncryption.setEncryptSymmKey(true);
        org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();
        secHeader.setMustUnderstand(false);
        secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);
        wsEncryption.build(doc, crypto, secHeader);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```